# Visual Studio Guidance: Whats the right way since its 'outdated'?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, architecture

So I want to build some automated guidance for our architecture. I found the automation toolkit and extensions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709808.aspx but they're flagged as outdated and no longer being maintained.

Great, but there's no reference to what the replacement is.. Is there one? What's the correct approach? I basically want to give our junior devs a way to right click and 'add new' for our specific architecture -- i.e. a new webservice might create a skeleton DTO, entity, WCF, and a factory or something to that effect.

Are these now add-ins? Is this no longer even done?

Comment: There is link to official forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsgatk/threads You might get good response over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement is the [Feature Builder Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67b720f4-9a50-41cb-86a2-82e33b7c5fc4).

Comment: Is this really the same thing? It seems to let me add templates and a workflow, but I don't see a way to automate something like prompt for a service name, create IServiceName in the interfaces project, ServiceName in the service project, ServiceEntity in the Entity project and ServiceDTO in the DTO project..

Comment: [Microsoft Blueprints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179252.aspx) was a replacement for the Guidance Automation system. However, according to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mglehman/archive/2009/05/27/update-on-microsoft-blueprints.aspx) , Blueprints was superseded by the Feature Builder Power Tool.

Comment: In regards to your more specific questions, I'm not familiar enough with the technology to give an adequate response. Perhaps these [videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/FeatureBuilder) on Channel 9 or [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/threads) may provide more assistance.

Comment: Watching the videos now -- why oh why isn't there a nice, easy to read tutorial? Videos take forever, but it looks like it'll work. Thank you for the pointer!